# Are "keep standing" and "keep sitting" the correct imperatives to order somebody to be in the same position?

Tags: word-usage

"Keep writing" and "keep smiling", as a usage of keep, make sense but like this, can one use "keep standing" or "keep sitting"? Like if a teacher scolds a student and punish him to stand or sit continuously would it be correct to say "keep standing" or "keep sitting"? What are the alternatives if it doesn't make right sense can be used?

Comment: _Keep VERBing_ means to continue VERBing. If you were not VERBing, then you can't continue it. This goes for any action - _keep walking/running/typing/writing/looking_ If someone is standing, they can't keep sitting, for instance; first they would have to sit.

Comment: If somebody says someone to be in standing position, will keep standing be correct sentence?

Comment: If I believed that (a) you are in a standing position, and (b) that I have the power and desire that you continue standing, then _keep standing_ would be a correct thing for me to say (assuming, once again, that (c) you could hear me say it and (d) you would understand it as an instruction from me to you).

Comment: *Stay sitting* or *remain sitting* sounds much more natural to me. @JohnLawler — Aren't *sit*, *stand*, and *lie* a different sort of verb (compared to e.g. *write* and *smile*), and might that be what makes them not work as well with *keep*?

Comment: My instinct is that I have a slight preference for *keep standing* but *stay sitting* because standing is more active than sitting: you *keep* doing something, but you *stay* in an idle or motionless position. But I don't think any of the alternatives is wrong, and this is really a matter of opinion - if it was sitting up straight, *keep* might be preferred.

Comment: Stand up verb involves change in state so keep standing seems to give impression in mind as if somebody is standing up again and again.

Comment: Instead of *keep sitting*, I would say *remain seated*. For *keep standing*, I would say *don't sit down*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - there are many many ways to say the same thing, and everybody has their own preferences about "naturalness". Everyone is right, of course, because it sounds natural to them. Case closed.

Comment: Ravi, _stand_ can mean either _stand up_ or _be in a standing position. Keep standing_ would be understood in the second sense - it doesn't convey the impression of rising to your feet repeatedly.

Comment: @kate Bunting- Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For sitting, the most common idiom (of the ones I know) is "stay seated," though "remain seated" is also common ([see Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Keep+seated%2CStay+in+your+seats%2CRemain+seated%2CStay+seated%2CKeep+sitting%2CRemain+sitting%2CStay+sitting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3); my search is in upper case since these are often at the start of a sentence). "Keep sitting" is relatively rare and sounds unidiomatic to me.

For standing, the most common idiom (of the ones I know) is "remain standing," though "keep standing" and "stay standing" are also common ([again see Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Keep+standing%2CRemain+standing%2CStay+standing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)). So "keep standing" is in fact a valid choice.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, each answer gave  new insights, very helpful.